# iPhone: How to use UITableViewCell in two table views

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have 2 classes that inherit UITableViewControllers. And this two table views should use the same custom UITableViewCell. So how can I use a Custom UITableViewCell from a Nib File in two different classes ? The owner of the xib can be only 1 class.

```
@interface Class1 : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,
    UITableViewDelegate> {
UITableViewCell *myCustomTableRow;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *myCustomTableRow;





@interface Class2 : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,
    UITableViewDelegate> {
UITableViewCell *myCustomTableRow;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *myCustomTableRow;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `UITableViewController` sub-class say  `CommonTableView`. Make this as the owner of nib file. Then inherit the two classes you want to implement from `CommonTableView` Class. This will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my opinion , You should have to create Custom cell and and for other table you should have to create only XIB for that and use .h and .m file same...

just change controller in XIB...

Hope you understand..

See this [How to create Customcell](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) and [this](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/)

Comment: I don't get it. You meen to create class that inherit from UITableViewCell (Lats named it CustomCellClass), and that class will be as owner for xib ? And in Class1 and Class2 just create instance of CustomCellClass ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [UINib class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html). It allows for instantiation without parent, and also improves the performance by caching nib file contents.

```
@interface Class1 : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    UINib *myCustomCellNib;
}
```

... and the similar thing for Class2. Then, in viewDidLoad

```
myCustomCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"myCustomCellNibName" bundle:nil];
```

then, when creating the cell:

```
NSArray* objects = [myCustomCellNib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
// given that your cell is defined as a first object in your nib
cell = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
```